# Embed Local .swf File in HTML

Tags: html, flash

I'm trying to create a small website that has a large amount of .swf files. However, I can't figure out how to embed them. I plan on just placing them all in the same folder as the .html file and have them embedded on the website. I also want this to be portable, so it accesses the .swf files based on the folder rather than the whole file location. Is there a piece of code that I can just enter the name of the .swf file and have it be embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use embed in your HTML code :

```
<embed src="myFile.swf"  height="800px" width="600px">
```

[source tutorial: html5 embed flash element](http://www.w3resource.com/html5/embed-element.php)

Comment: Does the "FOLDER" part mean that it's based off of the folder that it's in? Also would the full code be: `<embed src="Location" height="300px" width="300px"></embed>`?

Comment: Stackoverflow wouldn't let me edit my comment. RIP.
**EDIT:** this is my code: `<html>
<body>
<a href="#GAMETITLE">GAMETITLE</a><br>
<h2><a name="GAMETITLE">TITLE</a></h2><br>
<embed src="FOLDER/SWFFILENAME.swf" height="480px" width="640px"></embed
</body>
</html>` I replaced the actual names with text that isn't correct, but I can assure you the code on my file is correct and contains the correct filename (unless i am supposed to replace FOLDER with the folder name), but in place of the swf location, its empty.

Comment: @WhyIsCode, What browser? Does it work if you simply use `src=myFile.swf`? (whereby your **.swf** is to be placed in same location as the embedding **.html** file). Does **[this other page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed)** work (shows fireworks) on your browser? If yes, then edit that shown code with your own swf link `http://www...etc` and then test changes with green "Run" button. Also look into using [**swfObject**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=swfObject)...

Comment: I'm using Firefox and IE. as a test, here's my code: `<html>
<body>
<a href="#AchievementUnlocked3">Achievement Unlocked 3</a><br>
<h2><a name="AchievementUnlocked3">Achievement Unlocked 3</a></h2><br>
<embed src="FOLDER/AchievementUnlocked3.swf" height="480px" width="640px"></embed
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: it just displays an empty page with the text on it. the html file displayed: [website](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=j5xdv9&s=9)         the folder: [files](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=nl343o&s=9) **EDIT:** Wow. The "folder/" part broke the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example for you. You need to change example.swf to your own.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>example SWF</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffff99;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashContent">
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="example.swf" width="822" height="550" id="example" style="float: none; vertical-align:middle">
                <param name="movie" value="example.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffff99" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```